# Admob ads not showing on phonegap build app

Tags: cordova, admob

i have created a simple app in phonegap and published it on playstore .i also link it with Google admob account and choose the two ads type banner and interstitial ads ,But when anyone opens my app it doesn't showing any ads or banners .please help me what can i do .I have Build my app using Html ,Css And jquery

Answer (score 0):

To show ads in your app the easiest way is to use a plugin. Here you can find the working one: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova. To use in Phonegap Build, place the following tag in your config.xml file:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-admob" source="npm"/>
```

Or to use in local phonegap app:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-admob
```

Then in your js code:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
  document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

  // Set AdMobAds options:
  admob.setOptions({
    publisherId:          "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",  // Required
    interstitialAdId:     "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII",  // Optional
  });

  // Start showing banners (atomatic when autoShowBanner is set to true)
  admob.createBannerView();

  // Request interstitial (will present automatically when autoShowInterstitial is set to true)
  admob.requestInterstitialAd();
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

Comment: Well i embeded the code you provided .and now how can i test that the coding is working and showing the ads.

Comment: See here: https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/setOptions you have the option to place "isTesting" flag in initializing options. You won't receive any ads in browser or emulator¿? (maybe), has to be real device

Comment: I have added all the codings in my config.xml file and index .html file but the problem is same . No banner or full screen ads showing on my ad . i installed it from play store on another person mobile to see the effects but its doesn't showing any ads

Comment: Maybe you can post config.html, index.html, javascript code (or you can publish via dropbox or send me at miqmago gmail)

Comment: ok i am sending you my project .see what is the problem in it